# Create following UI and Head-Lock UI in VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, unity-ui

**GOAL**

I imported Meta XR Integration package and Meta XR Simulator.

I want to follow and head-lock UI to Headset Camera.

**CONTENT**

I use Built-in and Unity2022.3.8f1. I am using Meta XR Integration 57.0.

I tried for Screen Overlay Mode and set child canvas object of headset camera in the World Space Mode.

[Child GameObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axicq.png)

[Canvas Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcNul.png)

Screen Overlay mode is not working and UI showed to underlay of gameobject in World Space mode.

And world space mode, UI is shaking when moving headset.

Please Help Me .